# How to use installed package in jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am having difficulties setting up a jupyter notebook environment, using external packages.

```
!pip install progress.bar
```

leads to:

```
Collecting progress.bar
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b4/fb/d45c6a34e1242f4c7abef5f98aeb29e7096518defcf390bd601b5d3148ff/progress_bar-8.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: progress.bar
  Building wheel for progress.bar (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for progress.bar: filename=progress_bar-8-cp36-none-any.whl size=5587 sha256=46b6c1e0cf1940b29e9e7208d4057a4d65986f9e793cea4b369ea833de896108
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/04/7e/72/b2261521999fc5bc4ca704b6d84722270d478643c366c6594e
Successfully built progress.bar
Installing collected packages: progress.bar
Successfully installed progress.bar
```

which is a success.

But then, how to use this?

Neither of these 3 worked:

```
bar = Bar()  # Bar is not definied
import progress.bar   #progress it not definied
bar = progress.bar.Bar()  #progress is not definied
```

Comment: Use `import progressbar`

Comment: kill me now.  Thank you!

Comment: actually I wanted the progress.bar   package since progressbar is a different one, but yeah thats how the mistake happened